# How to add Javascript variable into div to allow formatting from CSS

Tags: javascript

My goal is to add three Javascript variables into `div`'s to allow formatting from CSS.  How do I get these items in `div`'s?

```html
function myWindow()
{
 visitorEmail = document.getElementById("myEmail").value;
 var findSymbol = /[@]/g;
 var result = visitorEmail.match(findSymbol);
 if (result != "@") {
  document.getElementById("myEmail").focus();
 }
 else {
     visitorName = document.getElementById("myName").value;
  visitorAddress = document.getElementById("myAddress").value;
  visitorPhone = document.getElementById("myPhone").value;
  visitorPersonal = document.getElementById("myPersonal").value;
  visitorCareer = document.getElementById("myCareer").value;
  visitorEdu = document.getElementById("myEdu").value;
  visitorEmp1 = document.getElementById("myEmp1").value;
  visitorEmpDets1 = document.getElementById("myEmpDets1").value;
  visitorEmp2 = document.getElementById("myEmp2").value;
  visitorEmpDets2 = document.getElementById("myEmpDets2").value;
  visitorEmp3 = document.getElementById("myEmp3").value;
  visitorEmpDets3 = document.getElementById("myEmpDets3").value;
  visitorEmp4 = document.getElementById("myEmp4").value;
  visitorEmpDets4 = document.getElementById("myEmpDets4").value;
  visitorRef = document.getElementById("myRef").value;
  
     myTop = ("<html>\n<head>\n<title>Resume</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n");
     myTop += (visitorName + "<br>");
  myTop += (visitorAddress + "<br>");
  myTop += (visitorPhone + "<br>");
  myTop += (visitorEmail + "<hr>" + "<br>");
  
  myText = ("<html>\n<head>\n<title>Resume</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n");
  myText += (visitorPersonal + "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorCareer + "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEdu += "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmp1 += "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmpDets1 += "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmp2 += "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmpDets2 += "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmp3 += "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmpDets3 += "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmp4 += "<br>");
  myText += (visitorEmpDets4 += "<br>"+ "<br>");
  myText += (visitorRef += "<br>");
     myText += ("</body>\n</html>");
  
  myHeadings = ("<html>\n<body>\n");
  myHeadings += ("PERSONAL INFORMATION"+ "<br>");
  myHeadings += ("CAREER OBJECTIVES"+ "<br>");
  myHeadings += ("EDUCATIONAL BACKGROUND"+ "<br>");
  myHeadings += ("EXPERIENCE"+ "<br>");
  myHeadings += ("BUSINESS REFERENCES"+ "<br>");
  
     flyWindow = window.open('about:blank','myPop','width=600,height=500,left=200,top=200');
     flyWindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsStyles.css" /></head><body><div>' + myTop + myText + '</div></body></html>');
 }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lot of typing. I would wrap all those repeating `<br>`-s with `<li>`. Porbably i would need to write function that takes some string argument and inserts into `<li>`. I would create array of strings from your form and iterate through them with given function like this:

```
const array = [visitorName, visitorAddress, visitorPhone...];

function createLi(string){
    return `<li>${string}</li><br>`;
}

array.map(item => createLi(item));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I vaguely remember this, but now I have something to research.  ;-)

Comment: @Brian Thacker _ Staff - Rolesv There is some ES6 stuff going on like [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and vanilla [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) method